# How to make sure my jQueryUI button text isn't longer than 25 characters?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, string, button

To avoid causing problems for my layout, how do I make sure my button text isn't longer than 25 characters?

```
var fileName = "AnalysisOfCollateralDebt";

$('#buttonContainer')
.append("<button id='fileButton' class='span-1'>Show File" 
+ fileName 
+ "</button>");

$("#fileButton").button({
    icons: {primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-e"},
    text: true
});
```

In the example above, the button would read:

```
Show File: AnalysisOfCollateralDebt
```

but I want it to read:

```
Show File: AnalysisOf...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change line 5 to this:

```
+ fileName.substr(0,10) + ((fileName.length > 10)?'...':'')
```

in English:

`fileName.substr(0,10)`: First 10 chars of the file name; if file name is shorter than 10 chars `.substr()` will have no effect.

`((fileName.length > 10)?'...':'')`: if file name is indeed longer than 10 chars, print out `'...'`.